# How to format a single line using column?

Tags: shell, sed, command-line, columns

I have a basic phone book in a file phonebook.dat.

```bsh
$ cat phonebook.dat
Onkh,Gregor:0123456789
Steinert,Franz:02473894091
Rubrecht,Magdalena:01474653371
```

I can then format this file using `column`

```bsh
$ column -t -s ",:" phonebook.dat
Onkh      Gregor     0123456789
Steinert  Franz      0247389409
Rubrecht  Magdalena  01474653371
```

But what if I just want to output one line of the file?
Based on the `man` page, `column` requires a file as its last parameter.

I tried working around this problem, but using for example `sed` to replace "," and ":" gives inconsistent outcomes as seen here:

```
$ sed 's/,/\t/g; s/:/\t/g' telefonbuch.dat
Onkh    Gregor  0123456789
Steinert        Franz   02473894091
Rubrecht        Magdalena       01474653371
```

How can I format a single line from a file using `column`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want `column` to only format a single line, then give only a single line to the utility.  Below, I format only line 2 from your example data:

```bsh
$ sed -n '2p' file | column -s ',:' -t
Steinert  Franz  02473894091
```

The file name argument to `column` is optional, and the utility reads from standard input if it is missing.  In the above pipeline, we use this fact to format the output of the `sed` command.

You may use any command to extract data from your phone book.  Here I'm using an `awk` command to output the entries with `Magdalena` in the 2nd field:

```bsh
$ awk -F '[,:]' '$2 == "Magdalena"' file | column -s ',:' -t
Rubrecht  Magdalena  01474653371
```

```bsh
$ awk -v name="Magdalena" -F '[,:]' '(family != "" && $1 == family) || (name != "" && $2 == name)' file | column -s ',:' -t
Rubrecht  Magdalena  01474653371
$ awk -v family="Rubrecht" -F '[,:]' '(family != "" && $1 == family) || (name != "" && $2 == name)' file | column -s ',:' -t
Rubrecht  Magdalena  01474653371
```

Comment: Using your answer, that column does _not_ need a file as last parameter, I found a way to make your first approach a bit more flexible for scripts without specifying a specific line to print out and also without the need of using `sed`: `grep Magdalena file | column -s ',:' -t`, or for a script `grep $search-for-me file | column -s ',;' -t`.

Comment: @LucaSchulz Good! Note that your `grep` command would search for the _substring_ `Magdalena` anywhere on each line.  This may be what you want, but it may also give false positives depending on the data in the file and the uniqueness of the search term that you are using.  My `awk` command gets around that by doing a string comparison with the entries in the 2nd field only (assuming we know that `Magdalena` is a name that we'd like to search for in that field only).

Comment: @LucaSchulz See also added bits now.